# Title Attribute in Links with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Add Title Attribute Tag in All Links, which must be same as anchor text with the help of Javascript?

Comment: So select all the  anchor elements, loop over them, read the text, set the attribute.

Comment: Can you include `html` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: You should specify more information about your situation. Maybe post some example code of your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a loop get the text using `.text()` append it to the attribute using `.attr()`:

```
$('a').each(function(){
$(this).attr('title',$(this).text());
});
```

or pure js:

```
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i in a) {
        a[i].setAttribute("title", a[i].innerHTML);
    }
```

Comment: i want to apply attrb in all links, which are not defined by any id or class.

Comment: why not working for me? i tried Kalpesh Singh's Code, and it worked, but in selected class only.

Answer (score 1):

simply try

```
$( "a" ).each( function(){

   $( this ).attr( "title", $( this ).text() );

} );
```

Comment: i want to apply attrb in all links, which are not defined by any id or class.

Comment: @MissingTricks since I  have not applied any selector after `a`, it will apply to all the links.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').attr('title', "I'm Set on all links")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="#">I'm Link</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">I'm Link</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">I'm Link</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">I'm Link</a>
</p>
```

**Logic**
1. Hold the anchor tag
2. set `title` attribute

Comment: i want to apply attrb in all links, which are not defined by any id or class.

Answer (score 0):

Finally This Code worked for me

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').each(function(){
$(this).attr('title',$(this).text());
});
});
</script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks to all Guys who answered this Question.